# Retrieve feature type from OpenCV FeatureDetector

Tags: c++, opencv

In OpenCV, it is very common to create a `cv::FeatureDetector` by providing the name of the feature:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector = cv::FeatureDetector::create("SURF");
```

This is a factory pattern, being `cv::FeatureDetector` an abstract class.

Then, given a variable of type `cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector>`, is it possible to retrieve the name of the feature? It is `"SURF"` in my example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Classes derived from `cv::Algorithm` inherit a `name()` method which returns a string containing the algorithm name. In the case of your SURF detector, `name()` returns the string

> Feature2D.SURF

which is a human-readable form. In general, this string is of the form *algorithm-type*.*instance-name*, though a very few just have a single-word description. For any of the feature detection algorithms, the *algorithm-type* prefix is always `Feature2D`. You can parse it yourself if you need an exact string match.

```
auto surf = cv::FeatureDetector::create("SURF");
auto n = surf->name();
std::cout << n << std::endl; // Prints "Feature2D.SURF", sans quotes
```